# What is the Content-type that we should be using in the JWT response?

Tags: android-pay

In the Google Wallet Objects API, can the Content-type in the JWT response just be plain text or is there a specific way it has to be presented?

Comment: Can you pls clarify your question - re: which response to which Wallet API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not check the Content-Type on the response, you can use either application/json or text/plain as the Content-Type.